# Do tsunamis accelerate on land?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acceleration, tsunami

> Before they saw the footage, Fritz and Synolakis couldn't understand why so many people had taken photos posing with the wave behind them, out on the open ocean. For some victims, those pictures would be the last of their lives. But the analysis showed that while normal waves slow when they hit dry land, tsunamis accelerate, catching people by surprise.

https://www.wired.com/story/amateur-video-helping-understand-deadly-tsunamis/

The only correct interpretation I can see is that the wave becomes a standing wave dye to the relative steepness if the coast, then accelerates when level ground is reached.

Answer (score 1):

> the wave becomes a standing wave due to the relative steepness if the coast

I think you mean that it "stands up" and becomes a [*breaking* wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_wave). A standing wave is [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave).

> ...then accelerates when level ground is reached

Just the opposite. A tsunami slows down when it reaches shore. Tsunamis travel at hundreds of kilometers per hour in deep water, and the wave height is so small (about one meter) and the period is so long (tens of minutes) that they go past boats at sea without the crew even noticing. But, when the wave approaches the coastline, it slows down, and it "piles up," and floods the shore.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsunami#Characteristics

---

Edit:

I looked at the article, and it is not clear to me that the author was talking about the speed of the *wave* when they wrote "...tsunamis accelerate." I think they were talking about the speed of the flood waters rushing inland.

You can find videos of tsunamis coming ashore on YouTube, and they are scary. Even if the wave doesn't actually break and come ashore as the proverbial "wall of water," the water level *rises,* and it keeps rising over a span of many minutes.

In one video that I remember, you see a trickle of water run down a street. It grows into a stream, and in less than a minute, the whole street has become a river. Half a minute later, it's a waist deep raging river, cars are being swept away, store fronts start to cave in, and the water keeps rising.

I've spent a lot of time kayaking on whitewater rivers, and I can tell you that most people do not appreciate the power of swift water. No surprise to me that some people would still be taking selfies only moments before they were swept away and drowned.